# git: command not found

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, git

Using github for the first time. In terminal I receive this error

```
git: command not found
```

If I type in terminal

```
which git
```

it returns nothing. If I type

```
which github
```

it returns `/usr/local/bin/github`

Github's command line utility seems to be installing a github but not a git. `echo $PATH` returns `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin`. Currently do not have a .bash_profile or .profile. Not sure if that is significant. Am a command line and $PATH rookie but am determined to learn. Mac OS version 10.6.8 and Github version 1.2.8. All advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official git build can be downloaded from here:

http://git-scm.com/

Another source for git might be MacPorts:

http://www.macports.org/

Xcode 4.x installs git too; if Xcode 4.x is on your to-install list, you will get it that way. (I don't think you actually get any choice in the matter.)

Comment: I suggest you use macports

Comment: Thanks Tom (and codd) for the advice and the quick response. Just installed Xcode 3.2. Still no git command but I'll install macports next.

Comment: Agh, apologies, didn't mention that it is only Xcode 4.x that installs git. Sorry. I forgot about Xcode 3.x (I work with iOS, and they stopped letting iOS developers use it a few months ago). Answer edited...

Comment: @Tom Its OK. Your first answer, going to [http://git-scm.com](http://git-scm.com) is what I should have done first. That solves the git: command not found. Thanks again.